# Preview and final render of grass are different

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

I am making a park with a path in Blender, but I have a problem with the particles. I've put the emission number at 200000 (for starter). At Viewport Shading - Render the grass looks normal (full), but when I actualy render it, the grass doesn't look as it should. Under the path and outside of the camera view I've removed the grass with weight painting. I have no idea how to make it right, so I would be very very thankful for any help. ( Oh and changing the emission number doesn't help much)

Eva

[image: Viewport Shading - Render]

[image]

Comment: you probably have a modifier with different settings for render and view port

Comment: I had the subsurf modifier applied, and when I removed it, the grass looked normal. Thank you very much!